# i want to develop a facebook application which displays as to which song is being played on my system now?

Tags: facebook

as in gtalk , which displays the present song being played , i want a post to be posted concurrently on the wall , which displays which current song is going on my desktop , and details of that song . how to go about it?

Comment: Do you want to create an application for Facebook, or create an application that sends messages to Facebook, purely for your use?

Comment: i want to create a an appication for facebook . which can interact with your desktop

Answer (score 0):

You need :

- to create a facebook application (https://developers.facebook.com/apps).
- to create a way for your application to retrieve which song is being played currently. If songs are played through Spotify or other online service, you might want to connect to their services. Otherwise you will need to develop your own solution to find which song is being played on the machine
- to register an Open Graph action for your Facebook application
- every time the song change, your application will then push an Open Graph action with an object corresponding to the song being played